# Android 4 on Virtual Box network issue[android -> host]

Tags: android, networking, virtualbox

I installed `android-x86-4.0-RC1-eeepc.iso` on VirtualBox and I trying to setup the network configuration on my installation, but I never get an installation. I already tried to find something in google but all configuration didn't get a result. Did you have some idees how to configure my virtual machine?
Running on Windows7x64 and connection type is WiFI.

Ok I get running connection from my host to virtual box. I'm able to connect from my host to my android guest. Know I would ask if its possible to connect from my virtualhost to my host-system?

Answer (score 0):

If you read near the end of the [release notes](http://www.android-x86.org/releases/releasenote-4-0-rc1) page, the current build from android-x86 has known issues with Ethernet support. Your best bet right now is to use the build from BuildDroid.org / Android-dev.ro.

Here are some notes I used while setting up my Android 4.0.x virtual machine:

- I used their ISO dated [20120130](http://www.buildroid.org/Download/android-x86-vm-20120130.iso.gz) to install
- Configured VBox guest as Linux/Ubuntu with 1024MB of RAM
- Once the VM has booted, you will want to disable "Mouse Integration" - you can press <kbd>Host</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> or from the Machine menu choose "Disable Mouse Integration". If you don't do this your mouse will not work as a cursor.

The default Ethernet adapter will be configured as a NAT device, so depending on your needs you may want to configure the virtual machine to forward TCP 5555 if you plan on using adb for debugging.